# Оптимальный способ разделения массива JS и вывести в 2 разных местах?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

получаю с сервера массив категорий.
Есть такая задача, первые 4 элемента вывести в одном месте остальное в другом месте
Я использую такую конструкцию

**Место 1**

```
Restaurant.kinds.slice(0,3).map((kind:any, index:number) => {
                      return( 
                        <li key={index}>
                          <a href="#"  data-kind={kind.id} onClick={scrollToCategory}>{kind.name}</a>
                        </li>
                      )
                    })
```

**Место 2**

```
Restaurant.kinds.slice(3,-1).map((kind:any, index:number) => {
                          return( 
                            <li data-kind={kind.id} key={index}>
                              <a href="#" data-kind={kind.id} onClick={scrollToCategory}>{kind.name}</a>
                            </li>
                          )
                        })
```

Т.е методом slice, есть ли доугой более правильный вариант вывести ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через `filter`

```
Restaurant.kinds.filter( (_, index:number)=>index<3).map((kind:any, index:number) => {
                      return( 
                        <li key={index}>
                          <a href="#"  data-kind={kind.id} onClick={scrollToCategory}>{kind.name}</a>
                        </li>
                      )
                    })
```

также через `reduce`, но в таком случае комбинируйте сразу с `map`